# MariaDB insert into where

Tags: mysql, mariadb

New to sql/mariaDB. Looking for the correct syntax when trying to insert a value into a column where another column equals something.

so far this is what i've tried however this doesn't correspond with mariaDB syntax

```
   INSERT INTO client(payment)
   values
   (50.00)
   where client_info = 5359;
```

looking to insert the value 50.00 into payment where the column client info equal 5359?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) clause, as you are not trying to insert a new row, but **update** the existing row:

```
UPDATE client
SET payment = 50.00
WHERE client_info = 5359;
```